# Iterating over table multiple times Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I queried two databases to get two relations. I terate over those relations once to form maps, and then again to perform some calculations. However, when I attempt iterate over the same relations a second time, I find that no iteration is actually occurring. Here is the code:

```
dev_connect = dev_engine.connect()
prod_connect = prod_engine.connect() # from a different database
Relation1 = dev_engine.execute(sqlquery1)
Relation2 = prod_engine.execute(sqlquery)

before_map = {}
after_map = {}
for row in Relation1:
    before_map[row['instrument_id']] = row
for row2 in Relation2:
    after_map[row2['instrument_id']] = row2

update_count = insert_count = delete_count = 0

change_list = []
count =0
for prod_row in Relation2:
    count += 1
    result = list(prod_row)
    ...
    change_list.append(result)

count2 = 0
for before_row in Relation1:
    count2 += 1
    result = before_row
    ...

print count, count2 # prints 0
```

`before_map` and `after_map` are not empty, so `Relation1` and `Relation2` definitely have tuples in them. Yet `count` and `count2` are 0, so the `prod_row` and `before_row` 'for loops' aren't actually occurring. Why can't I iterate over `Relation1` and `Relation2` a second time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `execute` on a SQL Alchemy engine, you get back a [`ResultProxy`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.ResultProxy), which is a facade to a `DBAPI` cursor to the rows your query returns.

Once you iterate over all the results of the `ResultProxy`, it automatically closes the underlying cursor so you can't use the results again by just iterating over it, as [documented on the SQLAlchemy page](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#basic-usage):

> The returned result is an instance of `ResultProxy`, which references a `DBAPI` cursor and provides a largely compatible interface with that of the `DBAPI` cursor. The `DBAPI` cursor will be closed by the `ResultProxy` when all of its result rows (if any) are exhausted.

You can solve your problem a couple ways:

- Store the results in a `list`. Just do a `list`-comprehension against the rows returned:

  ```
  Relation1 = dev_engine.execute(sqlquery1)
  relation1_items = [r for r in Relation1]
  # ...
  # now you can iterate over relation1_items as much as you want
  ```
- Do everything you need to in one pass through each row set returned. I don't know if this option is feasible for you since I don't know if the full extent of your calculations require cross-referencing between your `before_map` and `after_map` objects.

Comment: Is there no way to reopen the cursor?

Comment: @JeremyFisher - As far as I know, SQL Alchemy/DBAPI don't offer support for [scrollable cursors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29#Scrollable_cursors), so the cursor you get back is a use-once-and-forget deal.

Comment: A rather more Pythonic way to compute the same result would be `relation1_items = list(Relation1)`.